# Serilog not working in Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am using [**Serilog**](https://serilog.net/) to write to a file and try to get more information about an error that is occurring in my production cluster...

In my local dev cluster the log files are created fine but they are not created in the VM's on my production cluster. I think this may be security related

- Has anyone ever had this?

> My production cluster has 5 nodes with a Windows 2016 VM on each

Even more strange is that this works on a single node cluster in Azure

```
    public static ILogger ConfigureLogging(string appName, string appVersion)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (sender, args) => Log.CloseAndFlush();

        var configPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
        var environmentName = configPackage.GetSetting("appSettings", "Inspired.TradingPlatform:EnvironmentName");

        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .WriteTo.File(@"D:\SvcFab\applog-" + appName + ".txt", shared: true, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
             .Enrich.WithProperty("AppName", appName)
             .Enrich.WithProperty("AppVersion", appVersion)
             .Enrich.WithProperty("EnvName", environmentName);

        var log = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();

        log.Information("Starting {AppName} v{AppVersion} application", appName, appVersion);

        return Log.Logger = log;
    }
```

---

*Paul*

Comment: Where are you creating the log files?  Can you share your Serilog initialization code?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend logging into local files in Service Fabric, since your node may be moved to another VM any time and you won't have access to these files. Consider using another sinks which write to external system (database, message bus or logging system like [loggly](https://www.loggly.com/))

Comment: This works fine when run under a single node cluster?  Is there a difference for 5 node clusters?  I thought that services are simply run on 1 of the 5 nodes available

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a permission issue. Your service might be trying to log to a folder where it does not have permission.

By default, your services will run under same user as the **Fabric.exe** process, that run as NetworkService, you can find more information about this on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security). 
I would not recommend this approach, because many reasons, a few of them are:

- Your services might be moved around the cluster so your files will be incomplete
- You have to log on multiple machines to find the logs
- The node might be gone with files (Scale up + Down, Failure, Disk error)
- Multiple instances on same node trying to access the same file
- and so on...

On Service Fabric, the recommended way is to use EventSource(or ETW) + EventFlow + Application Insights. They run smoothly together and bring you many features.

If you want to use stay on Serilog, I would recommend you use Serilog + Application Insights instead, it will give you move flexibility on your monitoring. Take a look at the Application Insights sink for serilog [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights).

Answer (score 0):

This was actually user error!  I was connecting to a different cluster of VMs than the one my service fabric was connected to!  Whoops!